# How to get the index of tuples in a 2D list?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

I need to get the tuple positions which are linked to each other with at least one element within it.

```
 [('1','1','1'),

  ('X','1','X'),

  ('Z','Z','Z'),

  ('Y','Y','X')]
```

Here, in 1st tuple value '1' present in 2nd tuple.
And, now in 2nd tuple value 'X' present in last tuple.

So, I need to combine all these into one list whereas tuple 3 values['Z'] are not matching with any other tuples. So, it is stored in separate list.

```
Expected : [[0,1,3],[2]]
```

My approach:

```
df = [('1','1','1'),('X','1','X'),('Z','Z','Z'),('Y','Y','X')]
res = [list(sub) for sub in df]
res
count=0
list_A=[]
for i,j in enumerate(res): 
    for m,n in enumerate(j):
        if res[i][m] in res[i]:
            print(res.index(j))
```

Comment: what is the expected behavior on [('1','2'),{'2', '3'), ('3','4')]? [0, 1, 2] seems off because 0 and 2 have nothing in common. You want [0, 1] and [1, 2]?

Comment: The tuple at 0 has common elements with 1 and the tuple at 1 has common elements tuple at 3 and hence all these are connected/linked. So the first list in my list of lists should consist of all the linked tuple's indices. The second list is the tuple that is left out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve with the index handling? ``i`` and ``m`` are already the indizes, and ``j`` and ``n`` are already the tuples and values. Your code *knows* the indices of the tuples it handles. What is ``res.index(j)`` supposed to do? Are you asking what is wrong with your current code, or how to solve the problem presented?

Comment: This looks related to topological sorting. What do you expect to happen with duplicate or cyclic links? E.g. what is the expected result for ``[('1', '2'), ('2', 'A'), ('2', 'B'), ('A', '4'), ('B', '5')]`` and ``[('1', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1')]``?

Comment: For the examples which you had given the expected output is, `[[0,1,2,3,4]]` and `[[0,1,2]]`. Another example for input `[('1', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('4', '5')]` the output should be `[[0,1,2],[3]]`. The output are the tuple indices which are linked through at least one element. Here, index 3 alone in separate list since index 3 elements doesn't have any common elements in other index values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
df = [('1', '1', '1'),  # 0
      ('X', '1', 'X'),  # 1
      ('Z', 'Z', 'Z'),  # 2
      ('Y', 'Y', 'X'),  # 3
      ('Z', 'Z', 'Z'),  # 4
      ('2', '2', '2')]  # 5
# first gather all the sublist numbers that intersect
out = []
for x in df:
    out.append({n for n, v in enumerate(df) if set(x).intersection(v)})
# then remove intersected (duplicated) sublist number subsets
output = []
while out:
    buf = out.pop(0)
    for x in out:
        if buf & x:  # intersection not empty
            buf.update(x)
            out.remove(x)
    output.append(list(buf))
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 3], [2, 4], [5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def find_linked_tuple_positions(tuple_list):
    tuple_list: list

    result_list = []
    checked_tuples = []
    for index, current_tuple in enumerate(tuple_list):
        if index in checked_tuples:
            continue
        linked_tuples = [index]
        result_list.append(linked_tuples)
        current_unique_items = set(current_tuple)
        for next_index, next_tuple in enumerate(tuple_list[index + 1:], index + 1):
            print(next_index, next_tuple)
            next_tuple_unique_items = set(next_tuple)
            match_items = [unique_item for unique_item in current_unique_items if
                           unique_item in next_tuple_unique_items]
            if match_items:  # tuples are linked
                current_unique_items = current_unique_items | next_tuple_unique_items  # updating set
                linked_tuples.append(next_index)  # updating the new link
                checked_tuples.append(next_index)
    return result_list


def main():
    tuple_list = [('1', '1', '1'), ('X', '1', 'X'), ('Z', 'Z', 'Z'), ('Y', 'Y', 'X')]
    result_list = find_linked_tuple_positions(tuple_list)
    print(result_list)
```